# (php) sqlite in-memory db gets "could not find driver" error

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

I have installed php7.1.7 in my Windows. New Laravel 5.4 install; tried configuring phpunit to use in-memory sqlite db as such

```
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
```

running vendor/bin/phpunit fails with:

> 1) Tests\Feature\ThreadsTest::a_user_can_browse_threads
>   Illuminate\Database\QueryException: could not find driver (SQL: select * from sqlite_master where type = 'table' and name = migrations)

If I try another value for DB_DATABASE, other than ':memory:' it fails with a database not found error, but not the 'could not find driver' error

Comment: You have to enable the sqlite driver in `php.ini`, than restart apache.

Answer (score 2):

open `php.ini` file. enable `php_pdo_sqlite.dll` by removing semicolon